# django URL Reverse : argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Tags: python, django

This is my urls.py conf

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^setting/', include('setting.urls')),
    url(r'^customer/', include('customers.urls')),
    url(r'^material/', include('materials.urls')),
    url(r'^order/', include('orders.urls')),
    url(r'^partner/', include('partner.urls')),
]
```

and my customers.urls conf

```
from django.conf.urls import url


from customers import views

app_name = 'customers'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list', views.customerList, name='customerList'),
    url(r'^create', views.createCustomer, name='createCustomer'),
    url(r'^remmove', views.lockCustomer, name='removeCustomer'),
    url(r'^update', views.updateCustomer, name='updateCustomer'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\S+)/$', views.customerDetail, name='customerDetail'),
    url(r'^member/(?P<customer_id>\S+)/$', views.customerMember, name='customerMember'),
]
```

and my template.html to use url reverse

```
{% for company in customers %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'customers:customerMember' company.id %}">
                                            <span style="color:#08c; font-weight: bold;">{{ company.name }}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ company.region_id }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ company.register_time }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {% if current_time > company.due_time %}
                                            <span class="text-center text-danger">Expired</span>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <span class="text-center text-danger">{{ company.due_time }}</span>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ company.account_limit }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ company.isdelete }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
```

when I visit http://localhost:8000/customer/list page, It gives me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError at /customer/list/

argument to reversed() must be a sequence
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/list/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument to reversed() must be a sequence
Exception Location: C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _populate, line 196
Python Executable:  D:\Code\Python\CXJ\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.4
Python Path:    
['D:\\Code\\Python\\SHCXJ\\apps',
'D:\\Code\\Python\\SHCXJ',
'D:\\Code\\Python\\CXJ\\venv\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
'C:\\Python\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python\\lib',
'C:\\Python',
'D:\\Code\\Python\\CXJ\\venv',
'D:\\Code\\Python\\CXJ\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Tony\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']

In template D:\Code\Python\SHCXJ\templates\customers\list.html, error at line 78
```

here is my customerMember view:

```
def customerList(request):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    if name is None:
        company_list = Company.objects.filter(isdelete=0).order_by('due_time').all()
    else:
        company_list = Company.objects.filter(name__contains=name).order_by('due_time').all()
    return render(request, 'customers/list.html', {'customers': company_list, 'current_time': current_time})
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check *all* of the `urls.py` that you include. It looks like you could have a typo, e.g. `urlpatterns = {...}` instead of `urlpatterns = [...]`.

Comment: no urlpatterns={...}, all urls is urlpatternes=[...]

Comment: I still think the problem could be in one of the urls.py that you have not shown. Try commenting the includes one by one, to see whether that stops the error.

Comment: Note that Django 1.10 is end of life and does not receive security updates anymore. Upgrade to the latest 2.0.x or 1.11.x LTS release if possible.

Comment: It's work now, in my partner.url used urlpatterns={...}, i instead of urlpatterns=[...]，it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in one of your other url patterns that you haven't shown in your question.

Check all of `urls.py` that you include. They should all be lists,

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

but it looks as if you are using a set somewhere:

```
urlpatterns = {
    ...
}
```

To help find the urls.py that is causing the issue, you could try commenting out the `include()` URL patterns one by one. If commenting out the include stops the `argument to reversed() must be a sequence` error, then you've found a `urls.py` that is causing a problem. Note that it isn't always easy to comment out includes like this - depending on your template, it might cause other `{% url %}` tags to fail.

Answer (score -1):

You're using an explicit namespace for the reverse in your template `<a href="{% url 'customers:customerMember' company.id %}">` but you're not defining the namespace in  your urls file; you need to add it as follows:

`url(r'^customer/', include('customers.urls'), namespace='customers'),`

Comment: The namespace isn't required - The OP has set `app_name = 'customers'` in `customers/urls.py`.

Comment: i have defined app_name='customers' in customers.urls as namespace, it's wrong syntax？